# Problems Cascading dropdownlist, generated dropdown isn't posting selected value to server

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Here is my view in image
[image]

The code is working fine, but...

When i submit the form, it only sends the value of first dropdownlist (I checked on browser network received arguments), also when i view the page source it doesn't show the generated options that I generated using ajax function.

Here is my Code

Action that generate my first dropdownList

```
public ActionResult TwoDropDownList()
{
    HotelContext H = new HotelContext();
    ViewBag.DropDownListOne = new SelectList(H.Continent.ToList(), "Id", "Name");
    return View();
}
```

Action that return json of second dropdownlist data

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult UpdateCountryDropDownList(int ContinentId)
{
    HotelContext H = new HotelContext();
    List<SelectListItem> CountryNames = new List<SelectListItem>(); 
    List<Country> Co = H.Country.Where(x => x.ContinentId == ContinentId).ToList();
    Co.ForEach(x =>
    {
        CountryNames.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = x.Name, Value = x.Id.ToString() });
    });   
    return Json(CountryNames , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

My Ajax call

```
@model Hotel.Models.Continent
 <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $("#Name").change(function () {
              var ContinentoId = $(this).val();
              $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  dataType: "json",
                  data: { ContinentId: ContinentoId },
                  url: '@Url.Action("UpdateCountryDropDownList","Home")',
                  success: function (result) {
                      var Country = "<select id='ddlCountry'>";
                      Country = Country + '<option value="">--Select--</option>';
                      for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                          Country = Country + '<option value=' + result[i].Value + '>' + result[i].Text + '</option>';
                      }
                      Country = Country + '</select>';
                      $('#Countries').html(Country);
                  },
                  error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                      console.log(arguments)
                  }
              });
          });
      })
</script>
```

My View

```
@using(Html.BeginForm()){
    SelectList se = ViewBag.DropDownListOne;
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.Name,se,"--Select--")
    <div id ="Countries">
       @Html.DropDownList("ddlCountry",new List<SelectListItem>(),"--Select--")
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" style="margin-top:100px;" />
}
```

HTTPPost Action

```
[HttpPost]
public string TwoDropDownList(string Name, string ddlCountry)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlCountry))
    {
        return ("you must select Both");
    }
    else
        return ("everything is working fine");
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already have a `<select>` element with `name="ddlCountry"` (generated by `@Html.DropDownList("ddlCountry", new List<SelectListItem>(), "--Select--")` but in the ajax call, you overwrite it and create a new `<select>` element without a `name` attribute (so its value is not posted back.

In the success callback, you should be creating `<option>` elements and appending them to the existing `<select>`

```
success: function (result) {
    var country = $('#ddlCountry); // get the existing element
    country.empty().append($('<option></option>').val('').text('--Select--'));
    $.each(result, function(index, item) {
        country.append($('<option></option>').val(item.Value).text(item.Text));
    });
}
```

Side note: Your methods should be returning a collection of anonymous objects, not `SelectListItem` There is no point sending extra data (the other properties of `SelectListItem`) across the wire when you don't use them.

Comment: Apart from these errors, the rest of what you doing is pretty awful - not using a model, use of `ViewBag`, no strong typed binding, no client side validation and weak server side validation. I recommend you study the code in Also recommend your study the code in [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1bPZym).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the end tag `</div>` for the `<div id ="Countries">`.

Try this:

```
<div id ="Countries">
  @Html.DropDownList("ddlCountry",new List<SelectListItem>(),"--Select--")
</div>
```